# UWP databinding

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, uwp

I want to make layout with table on page. Right now I have:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,0,10,0">
        <ListView 
            x:Name="NewsList" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Margin="15" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="25" Text="{Binding news_time}"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="15" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="25" Text="{Binding title}"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="15" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="25" Text="{Binding news_text}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I want to make binding for my `ObservableCollection` objects to add `Grid` rows dynamically to `StackPanel` tags. Here is my `.cs` file.

```
public class News
{
    public int id;
    public string news_time;
    public string title;
    public string news_text;
}

public sealed partial class TermsAndNews : Page
{

    public ObservableCollection<News> newsCollection { get; set; } =
    new ObservableCollection<News>();
 // ...
    // Method called on initialization
    private async void GetData()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var responsetNews = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:3000/news");

        responsetNews.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        string jsonNews = await responsetNews.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        this.newsCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<News>>(jsonNews);

        NewsList.ItemsSource = newsCollection;
    }
 }
```

After running the code, nothing is displayed. Any ideas ?

Comment: You have changed the actual collection and not notified the view, rather than the contents of the observable collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
this.newsCollection = .....
```

to

```
ObservableCollection<News> tempobcol = ...
```

then iterating through and adding to `newsCollection`

```
Foreach (News n in tempobcol)
{ newsCollection.Add(n); }
```

and finally, removing

```
NewsList.ItemsSource = newsColleciton;
```

in order to add it to the XAML

```
<ListView x:Name:"NewsList" ItemsSource:="{Binding newsCollection}"...../>
```